# Image watermarking algorithm

Tags: image-processing, fonts, watermark

I want to join an image with a text like in 'disneyland paris ticket on this site :

[image]

(which it given an alphabet 'A').
there is a mickey picture and many of tiling name on it.

is there anyone know how to implement this?
what algorithm I've to used?

Comment: Better go for a solid library that already implements such algorithms. Depending on the image format, you would have to write the algorithms against each specification. I can only imagine how troublesome that could be.

Comment: This probably isn't watermarking at all (on the ticket).  To me it looks like simply font pixel replacement of the pixels where the text is located.  A true watermark is normally an alpha blended set of pixels blended with the background image so that the image cannot easily be manipulated or stolen (this is not the ONLY type, but is probably the most common).  What are you TRULY trying to accomplish, and with what language, and platform?